# How to change ">1200" to 1200 in R?

Tags: r

We have a dataset that contains numeric values which are limited to a certain range. When the values are outside that range, they are simplified to `">1200"` and `"<75"`.

We would like to change these values to the maximum or minimum value in an automated way. So, `">1200"` should become `1200` and `"<75"` should become `75`:

```
[153] 240   645   85    235   >1200 715   235   150
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gsub` to match one or more instances of `<` or `>`, replace with blank `""` and convert to numeric.

```
as.numeric(gsub("[<>]+", "", v1))
#[1]  240  645   85  235 1200  715  235  150   75
```

If there is only one instance, we can also use `sub`

#### data

```
v1 <- c(240,   645,   85,    235,   '>1200', 715,   235,   150, '<75')
```

Comment: If the result is always nonnegative integers, `gsub("\\D", "", v1)` or similar also works.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like to rely on as many packages as possible because I'm a masochist, so I would use `readr::parse_number()`, if I were you:

```
> readr::parse_number(v1)
[1]  240  645   85  235 1200  715  235  150
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can just extract all the numbers from the vector and convert it into numeric

```
as.numeric(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x)))

#[1] 240  645   85  235 1200  715  235  150
```

or we can also use `extract_numeric` from `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
extract_numeric(x)

#[1] 240  645   85  235 1200  715  235  150
```

Comment: Note that `tidyr::extract_numeric` is deprecated for `readr::parse_numeric()`...which is deprecated for `readr::parse_number()`

Answer (score 0):

With `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

as.numeric(str_extract(x, '\\d+'))
# [1]  240  645   85  235 1200  715  235  150   75
```

**Data (from @akrun):**

```
x <- c(240,   645,   85,    235,   '>1200', 715,   235,   150, '<75')
```